# Efficient AABB/triangle intersection in C#

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d, geometry

Can anyone recommend an efficient port to CSharp of any of the public AABB/triangle intersection algorithms.

I've been looking at Moller's approach, described abstractly [here](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Tomas_Akenine-Moller/pubs/tribox.pdf), and if I were to port it, I would probably start from [this C++ version](http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Tomas_Akenine-Moller/code/tribox3.txt).  [This C++ library by Mike Vandelay](http://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=10317&lngWId=3) seems like it could also be a great starting point.

...or... any other "wheel" that can take a triangle of Vector3's and tell me if it intersects with an AABB), relatively efficiently.

There seem to be a variety of algorithms, but most seem to be written in c++, or just described abstractly in white papers and I need a c# specific implementation for our application.  Efficiency is not key, but c# is.  (though efficiency is obviously nice too of course ;p )

Any C# options, before I wade through a "math" port ;) would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in 3D or 2D?

Comment: I am looking for a 3D solution (trying to Voxelize a mesh in c#).

Comment: Do you just want to find out if they intersect or not, or do you want to find the line of intersection?

Comment: I just need a true/false indicating if they do (or do not) intersect.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

For any two convex meshes, to find whether they intersect, you need to check if there exist a separating plane. If it does, they do not intersect. The plane can be picked from any face of either shape, or the edge cross-products.

The plane is defined as a normal and an offset from Origo. So, you only have to check three faces of the AABB, and one face of the triangle.

```
bool IsIntersecting(IAABox box, ITriangle triangle)
{
    double triangleMin, triangleMax;
    double boxMin, boxMax;

    // Test the box normals (x-, y- and z-axes)
    var boxNormals = new IVector[] {
        new Vector(1,0,0),
        new Vector(0,1,0),
        new Vector(0,0,1)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Project(triangle.Vertices, boxNormals[i], out triangleMin, out triangleMax);
        if (triangleMax < box.Start.Coords[i] || triangleMin > box.End.Coords[i])
            return false; // No intersection possible.
    }

    // Test the triangle normal
    double triangleOffset = triangle.Normal.Dot(triangle.A);
    Project(box.Vertices, triangle.Normal, out boxMin, out boxMax);
    if (boxMax < triangleOffset || boxMin > triangleOffset)
        return false; // No intersection possible.

    // Test the nine edge cross-products
    IVector[] triangleEdges = new IVector[] {
        triangle.A.Minus(triangle.B),
        triangle.B.Minus(triangle.C),
        triangle.C.Minus(triangle.A)
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        // The box normals are the same as it's edge tangents
        IVector axis = triangleEdges[i].Cross(boxNormals[j]);
        Project(box.Vertices, axis, out boxMin, out boxMax);
        Project(triangle.Vertices, axis, out triangleMin, out triangleMax);
        if (boxMax < triangleMin || boxMin > triangleMax)
            return false; // No intersection possible
    }

    // No separating axis found.
    return true;
}

void Project(IEnumerable<IVector> points, IVector axis,
        out double min, out double max)
{
    double min = double.PositiveInfinity;
    double max = double.NegativeInfinity;
    foreach (var p in points)
    {
        double val = axis.Dot(p);
        if (val < min) min = val;
        if (val > max) max = val;
    }
}

interface IVector
{
    double X { get; }
    double Y { get; }
    double Z { get; }
    double[] Coords { get; }
    double Dot(IVector other);
    IVector Minus(IVector other);
    IVector Cross(IVector other);
}

interface IShape
{
    IEnumerable<IVector> Vertices { get; }
}

interface IAABox : IShape
{
    IVector Start { get; }
    IVector End { get; }
}

interface ITriangle : IShape {
    IVector Normal { get; }
    IVector A { get; }
    IVector B { get; }
    IVector C { get; }
}
```

---

A good example is the box (±10, ±10, ±10) and the triangle (12,9,9),(9,12,9),(19,19,20).

The separating plane is the one where (12,9,9),(9,12,9) is lying and the normal is (-3, -3, 0), so they do not intersect.

The separating axis is <1,1,0>(you can also say that it is (-3, -3, 0)), which is obtained from the cross product between <0,0,1> and <-3,3,0>.

[image: Graph]

Comment: This looks PERFECT.  Having done a fair amount of research on this problem, this looks (massively) like the most efficient way to test for intersection...  Does this actually handle all of the many different edge cases for intersection?

Comment: I was close. In the 2D case that would have been enough, but in 3D you also need to check the edge cross-products.

Comment: Awesome, thanks - I will test it out!  I have found (in other testing) that for performance reasons it will probably run faster (while not being nearly as elegant) to harden the interfaces into actual classes and turn the properties into fields - but, this looks like a beautiful implementation of the separating axis algorithm.  Thank you again!

Comment: Link to paper: http://fileadmin.cs.lth.se/cs/Personal/Tomas_Akenine-Moller/code/tribox_tam.pdf

Comment: I don't understand the triangle normal test. Why is only one random vertex of the triangle tested, instead of all three?

Comment: @TysonJacobs The triangle normal is not a vertex. It is a directional vector perpendicular to the face of the triangle. It could be obtained with `Normal => (A.Minus(B).Cross(C.Minus(B))`

Comment: @MarkusJarderot I know, what I was asking is, why is only triangle.A tested? Why not all three vertices?

Comment: @TysonJacobs: You only need to test one vertex since they all project to the same point along the normal (due to it being the normal of the triangle!).

Comment: What is the physical interpretation of the 9 tests related to the edge cross-products? I read the paper by Tomas Akenine-Möller, but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44500/how-many-and-which-axes-to-use-for-3d-obb-collision-with-sat has a good explanation.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. Apart from the minor error that @RegisPortalez has pointed out in his answer, your answer is perfect. I have searched endlessly for a fast working impl of AABB/Triangle test and found none that works 100%, except yours. This should be a canned answer for this question 

Answer (score 9):

I noticed a small bug in this implementation which leads to false negatives. 
If your triangle has one edge parallel to one axis (for example (1, 0, 0)), then you will have a null vector when computing

```
triangleEdges[i].Cross(boxNormals[j])
```

This will lead to equality in the test below and give you a false negative.

replace <= and >= by < and > at line

```
 if (boxMax <= triangleMin || boxMin >= triangleMax)
```

(strict comparers to remove those cases).

Works well except for that!

Thank you

Comment: this line he means: if (boxMax <= triangleMin || boxMin >= triangleMax) edit that and it works flawlessly, Markus Jarderot did not fix it in his answer